# Issues viewing Rubocop & Ruby critic HTML outputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I'm using c9 as my dev environment for Ruby-on-Rails.

For one of my recent projects i've been using [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) and [RubyCritic](https://github.com/whitesmith/rubycritic) to critique my code. Both of which can output a beautiful formatted html dump of what they've found (eg. [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0M3029412x3O091a1X1R/expected.html)).

I'm pretty sure I've sucessfully previewed this within c9.io before... but currently i can't view them (if I git clone the files on my desktop, i can get them to run fine without modification so 99% sure this is a c9 settings issue).

The HTML dumps are stored at:

```
~/workspace/{my_project_root_folder}/tmp/rubycritic/current_file.html
```

and

```
~/workspace/{my_project_root_folder}/coverage/index.html
```

Normally i'd expect to just open the html file under live preview. I've used this before to preview markdown notes i've written from the root of a project - so I'd expected this to work.

[image]

But I get the following error:

```
Page Not Found
404 - preview File '/home/ubuntu/workspace/{my_project_root_folder}/tmp/rubycritic/current_file.html' could not be found!
We're sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found
```

Do I have to give permissions to the preview browser to render this file or something?

Why is it going wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's not interpolating `my_project_root_folder` correctly (or at all)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is exactly, but can you visit `https://preview.c9.io/<username>/<workspace-name>/` and then navigate to the file in question? Does that work?

Comment: Boom - that's it. So `https://preview.c9.io/{username}/{workspace}/{project-name}/coverage/index.html` gets me rubycritic and `https://preview.c9.io/{username}/{workspace}/{project-name}/tmp/rubycritic/overview.html` gets me rubocop - if you want to put that as a proper answer i'll mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: although this does raise the question of why the preview pane is opening the browser to `/home/ubuntu/workspace/` instead of `https://preview.c9.io/{username}/{workspace}/{project-name}/`